# How to get the current visible item in a Mui List?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm building a list that, when scrolling through the list, highlights the currently selected list item in a sidebar (see this [example](https://www.ubereats.com/de-en/store/citizen-cafe/SJOsrncmQQGRjCQ0MLf2HA?diningMode=DELIVERY&nt=1&pl=JTdCJTIyYWRkcmVzcyUyMiUzQSUyMkJhcmNlbG9uYSUyMiUyQyUyMnJlZmVyZW5jZSUyMiUzQSUyMkNoSUo1VENPY1JhWXBCSVJDbVpIVHozN3NFUSUyMiUyQyUyMnJlZmVyZW5jZVR5cGUlMjIlM0ElMjJnb29nbGVfcGxhY2VzJTIyJTJDJTIybGF0aXR1ZGUlMjIlM0E0MS4zODcyODUlMkMlMjJsb25naXR1ZGUlMjIlM0EyLjE2ODE5MDclN0Q%3D&ps=1) from uber eats). From my React Native experience, I would expect there to be something like a prop for the currently visible index to listen for the visible item in the list. However in React, I use the Mui list to implement this, but there is no such prop in the docs mentioned (I am not fixed to Mui list).

```
<List onVisibleItemChanged={(item)=>{console.log(item)}}>
          <ListItem disablePadding> Item 1 </ListItem>
          <ListItem disablePadding> Item 2 </ListItem>
</List>
```

I am happy for any hint that points in the right direction to search.

Answer (score 0):

MUI doesn't provide the functionality you described, the intended way to achieve this is to store the selected list item ID in some kind of state and style your list item if the list item ID is the same ID as the selected list item in state.

```
const [selectedListItemID, setSelectedListItemID] = useState<string | undefined>();

<List>
    <ListItemButton selected={selectedListItemID === 1}>Item 1</ListItemButton>
    <ListItemButton selected={selectedListItemID === 2}>Item 2</ListItemButton>
</List>
```

With this above pattern, you could now create a custom wrapper component around the above list that exposed a `onVisibleItemChanged` prop that fired when a ListItemButton was pressed